# Gravar dados de formulário em sessão

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Criei um formulário de acesso para minha área administrativa, usando um [tutorial da Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240/pt-br).

Agora preciso recuperar o login que ele digitou pra entrar e mostrá-lo em uma página de administração, e também para fazer futuras consultar ao banco de dados.

Como posso fazer isso? Me disseram pra guardar o login e senha em uma Sessão e depois recuperá-la na outra página, porém não faço a mínima ideia de como implementar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando está usando `FormsAuthentication` você poderá recuperar o usuário logado dessa forma:

```
string username = "";
if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

Comment: `username = xxx` <--- Existe ai uma questão com um fecho de `)`.

Comment: Obrigado Iuri, você salvou \o/

Answer (score 4):

Sessões são formas de armazenar dados que serão excluídos quando determinado evento ocorrer (no comportamento default do ASP.NET, quando 20 minutos se passarem desde a última ação do usuário, ou quando a janela do browser for fechada).

Criar uma session não poderia ser mais fácil:

```
Session["NomeDaSession"] = "ValorDaSession";
```

Verificar o valor da mesma também:

```
// Primeiro verificamos se a session existe
if (Session["NomeDaSession"] != null)
    // Operações pertinentes
```

No entanto, além de responder à sua dúvida, cabe a mim a recomendação do uso de uma tecnologia mais recente, **se você estiver trabalhando em algo novo**. Sei que, para legado, normalmente não há jeito. Ao invés de Web Forms, procure usar [ASP.NET MVC](http://asp.net/mvc) quando for pertinente.

Comment: A empresa onde faço estágio usa Webforms :/