# Armazenar dados de formulários temporariamente antes de gravar no banco de dados

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Como faço para armazenar dados de um formulário temporariamente antes de inserir no banco?
Tenho um formulário com um conjunto de campos. Após o usuário preencher o conjunto de campos, terá a opção de adicionar mais um conjunto com os mesmos campos para inserir novos valores. Gostaria de fazer a inserção no banco apenas quando o usuário finalizar o preenchimento. Cada conjunto de campos deve ser um registro na tabela. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Podes usar a `$_SESSION` para guardar esses elementos.

Comment: Vai funcionar para inputs com o mesmo `name`?

Comment: Relacionado: [Gravar dados de formulário em sessão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7991/gravar-dados-de-formul%C3%A1rio-em-sess%C3%A3o/8003#8003)

Comment: Ou podes sempre criar uma tabela temporária.

Comment: você quer guardar no usuário ou no servidor?

Comment: Quero guardar os dados no usuário

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar um array na $_SESSION e para cada conjunto você adiciona um novo índice no array. Para isso busque o tamanho do array e:

```
$_SESSION[$tamanho+1]['nome'] = $_POST['nome'];
```